# Overloading operator []

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, return-type

Let's say I have a container class called `MyContainerClass` that holds integers.
The `[]` operator, as you know, can be overloaded so the user can more intuitively access values as if the container were a regular array.  For example:

```
MyContainerClass MyInstance;
// ...
int ValueAtIndex = MyInstance[3]; // Gets the value at the index of 3.
```

The obvious return type for `operator[]` would be `int`, but then the user wouldn't be able to do something like this:

```
MyContainerClass MyInstance;
MyInstance[3] = 5;
```

So, what should the return type for `operator[]` be?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The obvious return type is `int&` :)

For increased elaboration:

```
int &operator[](ptrdiff_t i) { return myarray[i]; }

int const& operator[](ptrdiff_t i) const { return myarray[i]; }
// ^ could be "int" too. Doesn't matter for a simple type as "int".
```

Comment: Yes, with both `const` and non-`const` overloads.

Comment: BTW, why `ptrdiff_t` rather than `size_t`?

Comment: @UncleBens i prefer ptrdiff_t because that's what real arrays's op[] use too when they occur in overload scenarios.

Comment: <Nit Pick>Why is the `&` bound to the operator of the first and bound to the type on the second</Nit Pick>

Comment: @Martin it's some weird scheme i'm using. if i have "T", i tend to put the '&' on the name. If it's "T cv" i tend to put the '&' on the type :)

Comment: @Johannes Schaub - litb: Now I am really curious. Why? You don't tend to do things for pure shits/giggles so I suspect you have some mad cunning ubberplan that explains this.

Comment: @Martin no i don't have any ubberplan about it. It's just how I'm ending up writing it lol.

Answer (score 5):

This should be a reference:

```
int &
```

Comment: Usually you want to add a const overload for it too

Answer (score 2):

```
class MyContainerClass {
public:
  int& operator[](unsigned int index);
  int operator[](unsigned int index) const;
  // ...
};
```

Returning a reference lets the user use the result as an lvalue, as in your example `MyInstance[3] = 5;`.  Adding a `const` overload makes sure they *can't* do that if `MyInstance` is a `const` variable or reference.

But sometimes you want things to look like that but don't really have an `int` you can take a reference to.  Or maybe you want to allow multiple types on the right-hand side of `MyInstance[3] = expr;`.  In this case, you can use a dummy object which overloads assignment:

```
class MyContainerClass {
private:
  class Index {
  public:
    Index& operator=(int val);
    Index& operator=(const string& val);
  private:
    Index(MyContainerClass& cont, unsigned int ind);
    MyContainerClass& m_cont;
    unsigned int m_ind;
    friend class MyContainerClass;
  };
public:
  Index operator[](unsigned int ind) { return Index(*this, ind); }
  int operator[](unsigned int ind) const;
// ...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

`int&`

returning a reference allows you too use the returned value as a left-hand side of the assignment.

same reason why `operator<<()` returns an `ostream&`, which allows you to write `cout << a << b;`